# Sql server 2014 Paging performance?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I've got a sql that uses FETCH and OFFSET to choose between specific rows, however i'm concerned about the possible performance and cost of running theese queries within tables with lots of rows. Looking at FETCH AND OFFSET in sql server 2012 it seems like it has bad performance by looking here http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2010/11/10/denali-paging-is-it-win-win.aspx and as you also can see the memory used was 44mb for the 10 000 row table.

Questions:

1.should i worry about the performance using this method within sql server 2014 when the table grows?

2.have they done anything since to improve this?

3.Is there any alternative way of doing this that is considered better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I know that this is an old question but, if you read http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx you will find an excellent analysis about using FECHT and OFFSET vs ROW_NUMBER and how was improved since the SP1 of MSSSQL 2012.

Comment: I don't see anything about SP1 there?

Comment: and for ***Sql server 2014-2016*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, since MS SQL Server 2012, you can use this approach.